# How to find a value of a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I just started using MATLAB, and for that I am not familiar with MATLAB itself.
My sample code is as follows:

```
function Problem1 = BisectionMethod1()
    a = input('enter function:', 's');
    f = inline(a);
    iteration_counter = 0;
    al = input('enter left bound: ');
    ar = input('enter right bound: ');
    break;
    disp(f('al'))
    disp(f('ar'))
```

When I set a as x+1, and set my left and right bound as 1 and 2, it displays f(al) and f(ar) correctly.

The problem seems to begin when I have a coefficient in front of 'x'.

For example, when I set a as 2x+1, and set my left and right bounds as 1 and 2, MATLAB would give me error.

Like I said, I am new to MATLAB, is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One point I need to make is that multiplication requires a `*` operator.  By doing `2x`, MATLAB would interpret this as a variable named `2x` and MATLAB does not support variables where there is a number that comes first.  Therefore, you need to do `2*x + 1`.  In addition, you need to remove your `break` statement.  Your code will exit prematurely if you leave this in.

Also, simply remove the single quotes when calling `f`.  You are inputting the variable, not the actual name of the variable itself.  As such, you would do:

```
disp(f(al));
disp(f(ar));
```

Using your code, this is what I get:

```
>> a = input('enter function:', 's');
enter function:2*x + 1
>> f = inline(a);
>> al = input('enter left bound:');
enter left bound:1
>> ar = input('enter right bound:');
enter right bound:2;
>> disp(f(al))
     3

>> disp(f(ar))
     5
```

Comment: I don't get an errors.  I'll output my REPL.  Also, you need to remove the **break** statement.

Comment: so there needs to be a * in between x and 2... I did not know this until now... Thanks for your help!

Comment: my equations contain exponents, is there a way to input exponential equations like 0.5(3x^(2)-1)?

Comment: @user3282123 yup. Try `0.5*(3*(x^2) - 1)`